# gn generated Xcode project of WebRTC does not compile

Tags: xcode, webrtc, gn

This is the first time I am trying to build something from the source codes. I was trying to make a console program out of WebRTC native code.

I followed [official guide](https://webrtc.org/native-code/development/) and checked out the source code.

As the guide says,

> To generate IDE project files, pass the --ide flag to the GN command. See the GN reference for more details on the supported IDEs.

I used this command to generate Xcode project:

```
$ gn gen out/Default --ide=xcode
```

But the Xcode project generated does not compile. Xcode kept telling me it could not find those files.

Is it because I did not do `ninja -C out/Default`? I am confused — am I supposed to still compile the whole source codes using `ninja` while I have generated an Xcode project using `gn`?

Answer (score 0):

am I supposed to still compile the whole source codes using ninja while I have generated an Xcode project using gn? => yes

Comment: That is what I tried. But Xcode still reports errors when compiling. Is the generated Xcode project only meant to manage all source files, but not to be used for compiling and building?

Comment: you understand correctly. you are still compiling with ninja under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

See https://dev.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/debugging-on-os-x/building-with-ninja-debugging-with-xcode for further details on building with Ninja and debugging with Xcode.